# Applying Function with SlotSequence and Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, slot

I would like to apply a function to a list of lists, while using each of the 2 elements of the list in a SlotSequence in two different places in the function.

What I am working with is

`MyFunction[##[[1]]][##[[2]]] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`

which outputs

`MyFunction[{1, 2, 3}][{4, 5, 6}]`

However instead I would like the output without the `{` and `}`

`MyFunction[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6]`

This needs to hold for arbitrary lists of equal length `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}`. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `(MyFunction @@ #1) @@ #2 & @@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`?

Comment: Perfect! I had a hunch that it should have been done in two steps in a sense, but I had no idea how that might be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

User [Michel E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) has already given a good answer. An alternative is to use (hat tip to [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) for their suggestion):

```
Fold[Apply, MyFunction, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

which evaluates to the same expression.

I'm not sure what exactly your goal is, but note that the code above works for lists of arbitrary length:

```
Fold[Apply, MyFunction, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9}}]
(* MyFunction[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8][9] *)
```

For fun: in the case of two lists, you can also use pattern replacements:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} /. {{a__}, {b__}} -> MyFunction[a][b]
```

which yields, once again, the same output.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I actually like the fact that using `Fold` works for lists of arbitrary length because I might need to use that later in what I am doing.

Answer (score 9):

This gets the desired result:

```
(MyFunction @@ #1) @@ #2 & @@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
(*  MyFunction[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6]  *)
```